# error "debug assertation failed" when using char * in C

Tags: c++, char, heap-memory

The error I get when I run the following code is "Debug Assertation Failed... Expression _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)".

My readTXT method needs to be passed a char* object but I want to allow the user to select enter the value for themself.

```
char * mapName;
int main()
    {
        //load map
        int mapSelection;
        cout << "select a map";
        cin >> mapSelection;

        switch (mapSelection)
        {
        case 1:
            mapName = "walls1.txt";
            break;
        case 2:
           mapName = "walls2.txt";
           break;
        case 3:
            mapName = "maze1.txt";
            break;
        case 4:
           mapName = "maze2.txt";
           break;
        }

        map = readTXT(mapName, 8, 11);
        delete mapName;
    ...
```

This is the code for the readTXT method

```
double* readTXT(char *fileName, int sizeR, int sizeC)
{
  double* data = new double[sizeR*sizeC];
  int i=0;
  ifstream myfile (fileName);
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {

    while ( myfile.good())
    {
       if (i>sizeR*sizeC-1) break;
         myfile >> *(data+i);
         cout << *(data+i) << ' '; // This line display the converted data on the screen, you may comment it out. 
         if (i == 10 || i == 21 || i == 32 || i == 43 || i == 54 || i == 65 || i == 76)
         {
             cout << "\n";
         }
         i++;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
  //cout << i;

  return data;
}
```

Comment: Don't `delete` memory you don't `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this:

```
delete mapName;
```

because `mapName` comes from a string constant.  Only `delete` memory that you allocated with `new`.

String constants are built into your program, and don't need to be deleted.  And when you refer to one using a `char*`, you're not making a copy, so that doesn't introduce any need to delete.

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete memory that you haven't got from `new`:

```
delete mapName;
```

Remove the above line.

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: The you probably have something else similar to it in the `...` code that you didn't show us.